# How can I write the data input code to prevent infinite repetition?

Tags: c#, mysql, json, unity-game-engine

I don't know why the name and score stored in varchar format in mysql are in descending order by score using linkedlist, but it causes infinite repetition when saving the information.

```
`public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string addURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/db_add/";
    public string resultURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/db_connection/";

    PlayerDataVO[] ranking; 
    PlayerDataVO head = null;

    public void StartSendData()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SendData());
    }
    public void StartGetData()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetResult());
    }
    public void ReadData()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator SendData()  
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();   
    
        string n = "0000";    
        string s = "0000";      

        form.AddField("name", n);   
        form.AddField("score", s);  
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(addURL, form);  
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();  

        if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("UPLOAD COMPLETE");
        }
        www.Dispose();

        StopCoroutine(GetResult());
        StartCoroutine(GetResult());
    }

    IEnumerator GetResult() 
    {
        using (WWW www = new WWW(resultURL))   
        {
            yield return www;   
            byte[] bytesForEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(www.text);
            string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesForEncoding);
            Debug.Log(str);
            ranking = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerDataVO[]>(str);
            for (int i = 0; ranking.Length > i; i++)
            {
                string name = ranking[i].getName();
                string score = ranking[i].getScore();
                PlayerDataVO vo = new PlayerDataVO(name, score);
                if (head == null)
                {
                    head = vo;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(head.next == null)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(head.getScore()) < Convert.ToInt32(vo.getScore()))
                    {
                        vo.next = head;
                        head = vo;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        head.next = vo;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                PlayerDataVO prev = head;
                PlayerDataVO temp = head.next;
                print(temp.getName());
                while(temp.next != null)
                {
                    temp = temp.next;
                }
                temp.next = vo;
            }

            Debug.Log(head.getName());
            Debug.Log("데이터 길이 : " + ranking.Length);

           
            PlayerDataVO temp2 = head;
          
            while (temp2 != null)
            {
                print(temp2.getName() + " " + temp2.getScore());
                temp2 = temp2.next;
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

```
`[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerDataVO
{
    private string name;
    private string score;

    public PlayerDataVO(string name, string score)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public string getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }
    public PlayerDataVO next;`
}
```

I can't remember what I tried because I was debugging while in a state of body aches. I'm sorry.

I was expecting
The highest score is 1st and must be ranked in descending order of score.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the while loop has no comparison of the score to stop the iteration, so you cannot expect the result to be a sorted list. On top of that, this type of sorting algorithm is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it wrong. It's C#, not C++. Thanks for the help  
drescherjm . and I reedited the tag

Comment: I'm still a student learning programming, so I'm sorry. I'll rewrite the code based on your comments. thank  
Sven Nilsson

Comment: Why not use the standard List class? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-7.0

Comment: It was a task under the condition not to use standard classes. 
thanks Sven Nilsson

Comment: In general `WWW` is obsolete .. rather use `UnityWebRequest`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m your code, you’re not stepping through the linked list properly. You need to step through and update both the `prev` and `temp` pointers so the new `vo` can be inserted into the right place.

This should do the trick (written but untested):

```cs
PlayerDataVO prev = head;
PlayerDataVO temp = head.next;
print(temp.getName());

var s = Convert.ToInt32(vo.getScore());
do
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(temp.getScore()) < voScore)
    {
        prev.next = vo;
        vo.next = temp;
        continue;
    }
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp.next;
} while ( temp != null );

temp = vo;
```

Comment: thanks for your help Milan but I tried the solution, but the while statement doesn't work, and the first two values ​​are the end                                                                  When I posted the question, I edited the part that I posted by dividing the code incorrectly. I'm sorry, but could you look at it one more time? thank you